# Get Vue databound model from DOM element

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and and more accustomed to given the framework so far i've found often i need to reverse the way i'm thinking about a problem to solve it, but i can't seem to rework this problem.

Assuming a external library returns a DOM element... and that DOM element is bound to a data element in the virtual DOM by Vue... how does one get access to the data bound element?

e.g.

```
var myArray = [{id: 0, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}];
...
<li v-for="(item, i) in this.myArray" :key="i" :id="item.id"  >{{item.id}}</li>
```

assuming i'm have access to the DOM element of

```
<li id="0">0</li>
```

Is there a **Vue approach** to getting the original bound object from the DOM element?

I realize i can inspect the DOM element for the ID and the manually search my array for the matching item in the model.  But with more complex/nested scenarios this becomes less trivial.

I assume there is some utility to get the VNode or bound data model from the DOM element directly... but have only found the opposite approach via $refs etc.

Comment: How does the external library return a DOM element generated by Vue?  A code example would help.

Comment: I don't think Vue offers this. This information is lost when Vue generates the DOM. If you look on how render functions look like, you'll see that there's no reference to the original data in the DOM. Render will bake it directly into the DOM, there is no need for vue to keep this information.